# Why can´t Blender open my STL file?

Tags: import

I am trying to open this STL file https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/architectural-exterior/street-infrastructure/flag-and-animated#
But when I import it to blender, it just loads an orange dot. What is happening?

Comment: I gave it a try and that works.. Can you share a picture of what you obtain ? ... edit : it is big in dimension, that can be a clipping problem : have a look to 'N' panel on the right, then 'view' section then grow up the 'end' clip parameter

Comment: You need to know that the STL file format has been designed as a unit-less format. This means, the vertex coordinates will be stored as plain numbers without unit information, and the target system which does the import interprets them using the current scene units. In Blenders case, the scene units are meters. If the source system was set to centimeters or millimeters, the scale will be off by a factor of 100 or 1.000. The site you pointed out offers .fbx and .obj, those formats are superior anyways, as they also are able to transfer textures for instance.

Comment: reference here: http://www.fabbers.com/tech/STL_Format  "The object represented must be located in the all-positive octant. In other words, all vertex coordinates must be positive-definite (nonnegative and nonzero) numbers. The StL file does not contain any scale information; the coordinates are in arbitrary units."